# ¿Cómo obtener checkbox seleccionados?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, post, express

Este es mi codigo en la vista:

```
form(action="/evaluacion/usuariosSeleccionados", method="get")
                        each item in students
                            li.list-group-item 
                                div 
                                        a(href="/evaluacion/user/#{item.name}") #{item.name}   
                                input.filled-in(type='checkbox' name='seleccionados[]' id='#{item.name}')
                                label(for='#{item.name}')  
                        div.actions
                        input(type="submit", value="add")
```

y en mi servidor

```
router.get('/usuariosSeleccionados', function(req, res, next) {
// router.post('/usuariosSeleccionados', function(req,res){
    console.log("prueba",req.params.seleccionados);
});
```

me imprime "prueba undefined", como soluciono?

no me importa si se usa `get` o `post`

Comment: ¿Ya añadiste `bodyParser` al servidor Express?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía si trabajo con bodyParser, me pregunto si debo trabajar como http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108747/proper-way-to-read-checkbox-data-in-nodejs?

Comment: cambia `params` por `body`.

Comment: @HectorSeguro muestra el mismo resultado undefined

Comment: y quita `seleccionados` para ver que muestra.

Comment: Si envías el formulario por GET, entonces la query string está en `req.query`. El objeto `req.body` se usa en métodos POST y `req.params` para obtener parámetros, por ejemplo `/:id`.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía si uso .query muestra `pruebas ['on']`, no se porque

Comment: Es correcto, porque tienes un grupo de checkbox cuyos valores se envían en la query string y que será transformado en array por Express. Agrega los atributos `value` a cada checkbox para que se envíen en lugar de *on*.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía funciono deberias ponerlo como respuesta

Comment: Ya está, @hubman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si envías el formulario por GET, entonces la query string está en `req.query`. El objeto `req.body` se usa en peticiones POST y `req.params` para obtener parámetros de la URL, por ejemplo `/:id`.

Además, si envías checkboxes sin un valor, ten en cuenta que por defecto recibirás:

```
['on', 'on', 'on']
```

Para evitar esto, agrega un valor para cada checkbox por medio del atributo `value`, de modo que recibas un array con datos diferentes.

Comment: tengo otro problema, ahora estoy usando un formulario(la presente pregunta) pero tengo una variable que tengo que enviar por ajax, hice la prueba y no se activan los 2(el formulario y el ajax), como lo soluciono alguna idea? un boton activa a los 2(supuestamente)